# Associating objects with createInstance and setting it manually doesnt work

Tags: node.js, database, foreign-keys, relational-database, sequelize.js

I'm trying to first create a Post instance with sequelize and then to create several instances of Media and associate those with the post Instance. However, both methods fail. With the post.createMedia approach I get the following error message:

```
An error has occured.TypeError: post.createMedia is not a function.
```

When I try to set the foreign keys manually I can see the relation is not set (see bottom of post).

These are the relevant models and their relations

```
//define Posts
const Post = sequelize.define('post', {
    dueDate: {
      type: Sequelize.DATE
    },
    minStake: {
      type: Sequelize.INTEGER
    },
    title: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING
    },
    body: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING
    }
})

//define media
const Media = sequelize.define('media', {
  videoUrl: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING
  },
  pictureUrl: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING
  }
})

Post.hasMany(Media)
Media.belongsTo(Post)
```

This is the code where I try to set the relation with post.createMedia

```
app.post('/createchallengehandler', function(req, res) {
    let form = new formidable.IncomingForm()
    form.multiples = true;

    form.parse(req, function(err, fields, files) {
        let userId =  fields.userId
        let dueDate =  fields.dueDate //Datime, format: 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS'
        let body = fields.body
        let title = fields.title
        let minStake = fields.minStake
        let pictureArray = files.file
        console.log(files.file[0])

        User.findById(userId)
        .then( user => {
            return user.createPost({
                dueDate: dueDate,
                body: body,
                title: title,
                minStake: minStake
            })
        })
        .then( post => {
            for(let i = 0; i < pictureArray.length; i++) {
                cloudinary.uploader.upload(pictureArray[i].path, function(result) {
                    console.log(result)
                    return result
                })
                .then(result => {
                    return post.createMedia({
                        postId: post.id,
                        pictureUrl: result.url
                })
                .then( media => {
                    post.mediaId = media.id
                    })
                })
                .catch( e => {
                    console.log('An error has occured.' + e)
                })
            }
        })
        .then(() => {
            res.send({success: true})
        })
        .catch( e => {
            console.log('An error has occured.' + e)
            res.send({ success: false, error: e })
        })
    })
})
```

I get the following error:

```
An error has occured.TypeError: post.createMedia is not a function
```

Which should not happen

As a work around I tried to set the foreign keys manually, using the same models:

```
app.post('/createchallengehandler', function(req, res) {
    //let userId = req.session.userId //session 
    console.log("Reached post handler")
    /*  if(req.session.loggedIn === undefined){
        res.redirect("login")
    }*/
    let form = new formidable.IncomingForm()
    form.multiples = true;

    form.parse(req, function(err, fields, files) {
        //let charityId = req.body.charityId // niet mvp 2017-04-04 13:23:44
        //let tags = req.body.tags //is an array
        let userId =  fields.userId
        let dueDate =  fields.dueDate //Datime, format: 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS'
        let body = fields.body
        let title = fields.title
        let minStake = fields.minStake
        let pictureArray = files.file
        console.log(files.file[0])

        User.findById(userId)
        .then( user => {
            return user.createPost({
                dueDate: dueDate,
                body: body,
                title: title,
                minStake: minStake
            })
        })
        .then( post => {
            for(let i = 0; i < pictureArray.length; i++) {
                cloudinary.uploader.upload(pictureArray[i].path, function(result) {
                    console.log(result)
                    return result
```

> ```
>               })
>               .then(result => {
>                   return Media.create({
>                       postId: post.id,
>                       pictureUrl: result.url
>               })
> ```

```
                .then( media => {
                    post.mediaId = media.id
                    })
                })
                .catch( e => {
                    console.log('An error has occured.' + e)
                })
            }
        })
        .then(() => {
            res.send({success: true})
        })
        .catch( e => {
            console.log('An error has occured.' + e)
            res.send({ success: false, error: e })
        })
    })
})
```

This also doesn't work. When I look at the media table I can see the foreignkey is not set.:

```
 id | videoUrl |                                       pictureUrl                                        |         createdAt          |         updatedAt          | postId 
----+----------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------+----------------------------+--------
  1 |          | http://res.cloudinary.com/piepongwong/image/upload/v1490628695/dhm4c4pvjoggw8bc7fmg.jpg | 2017-03-27 17:31:35.697+02 | 2017-03-27 17:31:35.697+02 |       
  2 |          | http://res.cloudinary.com/piepongwong/image/upload/v1490628695/c3ftarncgcbvjw6tfz42.jpg | 2017-03-27 17:31:36.005+02 | 2017-03-27 17:31:36.005+02 |
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the manual approach. Classic, I forgot to set a curly bracket and a parentheses in this part:

```
.then( post => {
            for(let i = 0; i < pictureArray.length; i++) {
                cloudinary.uploader.upload(pictureArray[i].path, function(result) {
                    console.log(result)
                    return result
                })
                .then(result => {
                    console.log(post.id)
                    return Media.create({
                        postId: post.id,
                        pictureUrl: result.url
                    })
                })
            }
        })
        .then(() => {
            res.send({success: true})
        })
```

Should be:

```
.then( post => {
            for(let i = 0; i < pictureArray.length; i++) {
                cloudinary.uploader.upload(pictureArray[i].path, function(result) {
                    console.log(result)
                    return result
                })
                .then(result => {
                    console.log(post.id)
                    return Media.create({
                        postId: post.id,
                        pictureUrl: result.url
                        })
                   }) //changed
                })
            }
        })
        .then(() => {
            res.send({success: true})
        })
```